# Looping nested lists through Boolean if-elif-else conditions

Tags: python, loops, if-statement, boolean

I plan to analyse legislation for the proportion of opposition, coalition or cross bench bills.

I have written two simple checks using `any()` to check if the inner list of parties who co-wrote a bill are found in the lists listing opposition and coalition parties.

```
coalition = ['CD&V', 'N-VA', 'Open Vld']
opposition = ['sp.a', 'Groen', 'Vlaams Belang', 'PVDA']

parties = [['Groen', 'sp.a'], ['CD&V', 'N-VA'], ['sp.a', 'CD&V']]   # test cases, one for each outcome

check_op = any(party in parties for party in opposition)
check_co = any(party in parties for party in coalition)
```

I then loop through the list of lists and perform the checks using `if elif else`

```
for p in parties:
    if check_op is True and check_co is False:
        print("This is an opposition bill")
    elif check_co is True and check_op is False:
        print("This is a coalition bill")
    elif check_co is True and check_op is True:
        print("This is a cross bench bill")
    else:
        print('none')
```

The result is always:

```
none
none
none
```

Whereas I would expect:

```
This is an opposition bill
This is a coalition bill
This is a cross bench bill
```

When I try to go through the conditions using just one list of parties, instead of looping through nested lists, the result comes out correctly...

What am I doing wrong, how can I get the for-loop to go through the conditions and get the correct result.
Thank you.

Comment: Careful. When you say `party in parties`, this is looking for a string in a list of lists. `parties` is a list of lists, there are no strings in that list. As a result, both `check_op` and `check_co` will be `False`. Additionally, I think you probably want to do the `check_op` and `check_co` stuff inside your for-loop, not before it.

Comment: @PaulM.Thanks! Quite right... -_- lesson learned :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your values `check_op` and `check_co` should depend on the input list you want to test. So you should compute them inside your **for loop**, like this :

```
coalition = ['CD&V', 'N-VA', 'Open Vld']
opposition = ['sp.a', 'Groen', 'Vlaams Belang', 'PVDA']

parties = [['Groen', 'sp.a'], ['CD&V', 'N-VA'], ['sp.a', 'CD&V']]   # test cases, one for each outcome

for p in parties:
    check_op = any(party in p for party in opposition)
    check_co = any(party in p for party in coalition)
    if check_op is True and check_co is False:
        print("This is an opposition bill")
    elif check_co is True and check_op is False:
        print("This is a coalition bill")
    elif check_co is True and check_op is True:
        print("This is a cross bench bill")
    else:
        print('none')
```

Output :

```
This is an opposition bill
This is a coalition bill
This is a cross bench bill
```

Comment: Thanks! This fixes the problem with minimal adaptation or rewriting! I should have tried this sooner.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is that you are evaluating `string` with `List of Strings`. Try following Code:

```
coalition = ['CD&V', 'N-VA', 'Open Vld']
opposition = ['sp.a', 'Groen', 'Vlaams Belang', 'PVDA']

parties = [['Groen', 'sp.a'], ['CD&V', 'N-VA'], ['sp.a', 'CD&V']]   # test cases, one for each outcome


for p in parties:
  check_op,check_co = False,False
  for member in p:
    if member in opposition:
      check_op = True
    elif member in coalition:
      check_co = True
  
  if check_op and not check_co:
    print("This is an opposition bill")
  elif check_co and not check_op:
    print("This is a coalition bill")
  elif check_co and check_op:
    print("This is a cross bench bill")
  else:
    print('none')
```

Output:

```
This is an opposition bill
This is a coalition bill
This is a cross bench bill
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This fixes the problem, too! I have currently implemented phoenixo's answer, but as I develop the script I will see if I am better off with this one. Cheers